# Calling multi-statement TVF with different parameters in separate CTEs showing wrong results

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, common-table-expression

I'm trying to call a TVF twice with different parameters in the same query, but for some reason, when I join the results together, one of the results sort of masks the other. I've reduced my problem down to this small example:

Take this inline TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnTestErrorInline(@Test INT)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT ID, Val
    FROM (VALUES 
        (1, 1, 10), 
        (1, 2, 20), 
        (1, 3, 30), 
        (1, 4, 40), 
        (2, 1, 50), 
        (2, 2, 60), 
        (2, 3, 70), 
        (2, 4, 80)
    ) t(Test, ID, Val)
    WHERE t.Test=@Test
)
```

and an equivalent multiline function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnTestErrorMultiline(@Test INT)
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    Val INT NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Test=1
    INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, Val) VALUES 
    (1, 10),
    (2, 20),
    (3, 30),
    (4, 40);

    IF @Test=2
    INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, Val) VALUES 
    (1, 50),
    (2, 60),
    (3, 70), 
    (4, 80);

    RETURN 
END
```

If I run this query:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT ID, SUM(Val) AS Total
    FROM dbo.fnTestErrorInline(1)
    GROUP BY ID
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT ID, SUM(Val) AS Total
    FROM dbo.fnTestErrorInline(2)
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1 c1
INNER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.ID=c2.ID;
```

the results are as expected:

```
ID  Total   ID  Total
1   10  1   50
2   20  2   60
3   30  3   70
4   40  4   80
```

but when I use the multiline version of the function:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT ID, SUM(Val) AS Total
    FROM dbo.fnTestErrorMultiline(1)
    GROUP BY ID
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT ID, SUM(Val) AS Total
    FROM dbo.fnTestErrorMultiline(2)
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1 c1
INNER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.ID=c2.ID;
```

the results are incorrect - cte2 shows the same values as cte1:

```
ID  Total   ID  Total
1   10  1   10
2   20  2   20
3   30  3   30
4   40  4   40
```

Additionally, I only see this behavior when the `GROUP BY` is present. Without it, the results are fine.

Strangely, if I add another column to the second CTE, it changes the results:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT ID, SUM(Val) AS Total
    FROM dbo.fnTestErrorMultiline(1)
    GROUP BY ID
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT ID, SUM(Val) AS Total, SUM(Val+0) AS why
    FROM dbo.fnTestErrorMultiline(2)
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1 c1
INNER JOIN cte2 c2 ON c1.ID=c2.ID;
```

yields

```
ID  Total   ID  Total   why
1   50  1   50  50
2   60  2   60  60
3   70  3   70  70
4   80  4   80  80
```

It appears the extra column needs to reference a column in the TVF table - a constant value there doesn't change the results.

What's going on here? Are you not supposed to call a multiline TVF more than once per query?

I've tested this on SQL Server 2008 R2 and 2012

Comment: Am passing 3 to `fnTestErrorMultiline` in second CTE still i can see results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0395/13. Its weird

Comment: @MM93 that is weird! That does seem to imply the function is only running once since the second CTE wouldn't have any rows to join on. Looking at the query plan, it does show 'Table Valued Function' twice, so I really don't know what's happening

Comment: If I change the order (ie) passing `3` to `fnTestErrorMultiline` in first CTE I cannot see results

Comment: @MM93 also changing the order of which cte is referenced first - whichever comes first seems to determine which results are kept (cte1 JOIN cte2 vs cte2 JOIN cte1)

Comment: I guess terrible performance isn't the only reason to avoid multi-line table-values functions. Functionality sucks too.

Comment: Removing group by clause corrects the behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known bug in SQL Server where it can incorrectly spool the results for one instance of the TVF and replay them for the other (despite the fact that the other has different parameters and returns different results).

The bug has existed for some time but recent changes to the cardinality estimator mean that in 2014+ it is even more likely to hit this issue.

See connect items..

- [Unexpected results in SQL](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/781422/unexpected-results-in-sql)
- [Count wrong when function_1 inner joined to function_1](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/1769932).

NB: The execution plan looks as below.

[image]

It uses a [Common Subexpression Spool](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/28/partitioning-and-the-common-subexpression-spool.aspx) All three highlighted spools are in fact the same object, in the yellow operator the rows are inserted and then they are replayed in the green operators.

Adding

```
OPTION (QUERYRULEOFF  GenGbApplySimple, QUERYRULEOFF BuildGbApply)
```

avoids the issue and gives a different plan with correct results but this is not something I would use in production.

[image]

Comment: Would you avoid those query options for performance reasons or some other reason? I can test my query with these options vs building the query differently (table variable to hold the results or something) to see how it performs, unless the options have some other negative side effect. This particular query isn't run very often, so I can tolerate a performance hit if that's all it is.

Comment: And wow, I just looked more closely at the first connect issue you linked. Our examples were nearly identical.

Comment: @David they are undocumented, unsupported etc. materialising into a table variable would work. Or simply copy the function definition and have two identical versions with different names so you just avoid the self join would also work.